# Python Process cannot pickle

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

Code:

```py
from aiohttp import web
from aiortc.mediastreams import MediaStreamTrack
from aiortc import RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription
from aiortc.contrib.media import MediaPlayer
import asyncio
import json
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
from queue import Queue
import sys
import threading
from time import sleep
import fractions
import time

class RadioServer(Process):
    def __init__(self,q):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q
        self.ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.pcs = []
        self.channels = []
        self.stream_offers = []
        self.requests = []
    
    def run(self):
        self.app = web.Application()
        self.app.on_shutdown.append(self.on_shutdown)
        self.app.router.add_get("/", self.index)
        self.app.router.add_get("/radio.js", self.javascript)
        self.app.router.add_get("/jquery-3.5.1.min.js", self.jquery)
        self.app.router.add_post("/offer", self.offer)
        
        threading.Thread(target=self.fill_the_queues).start()
        web.run_app(self.app, access_log=None, host="192.168.1.20", port="8080", ssl_context=None)

    def fill_the_queues(self):
        while(True):
            frame = self.q.get()
            for stream_offer in self.stream_offers:
                stream_offer.q.put(frame)

    async def index(self,request):
        content = open(os.path.join(self.ROOT, "index.html"), encoding="utf8").read()
        return web.Response(content_type="text/html", text=content)


    async def javascript(self,request):
        content = open(os.path.join(self.ROOT, "radio.js"), encoding="utf8").read()
        return web.Response(content_type="application/javascript", text=content)

    async def jquery(self,request):
        content = open(os.path.join(self.ROOT, "jquery-3.5.1.min.js"), encoding="utf8").read()
        return web.Response(content_type="application/javascript", text=content)

    async def offer(self,request):  
        params = await request.json()
        offer = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=params["sdp"], type=params["type"])

        pc = RTCPeerConnection()
        self.pcs.append(pc)
        self.requests.append(request)
        
        # prepare epalxeis media
        self.stream_offers.append(CustomRadioStream())
        pc.addTrack(self.stream_offers[-1])


        @pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
        async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
            if pc.iceConnectionState == "failed":
                self.pcs.remove(pc)
                self.requests.remove(request)
                print(str(request.remote)+" disconnected from radio server")
                print("Current peer connections:"+str(len(self.pcs)))

        # handle offer
        await pc.setRemoteDescription(offer)

        # send answer
        answer = await pc.createAnswer()
        await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
        
            

        return web.Response(content_type="application/json",text=json.dumps({"sdp": pc.localDescription.sdp, "type": pc.localDescription.type}))

    async def on_shutdown(self,app):
        # close peer connections
        if self.pcs:
            coros = [pc.close() for pc in self.pcs]
            await asyncio.gather(*coros)
            self.pcs = []
            self.channels = []
            self.stream_offers = []
            
"""
some other classes here such as CustomRadioStream and RadioOutputStream
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support()
    q = Queue()
    custom_server_child_process = RadioServer(q)
    custom_server_child_process.start()
```

Error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 106, in <module>
    custom_server_child_process.start()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, i
n start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, i
n _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 327, i
n _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py", l
ine 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60,
in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

What I am doing wrong?
If I call the run function (instead of start) directly, then there is no problem, but i want to use processing for this class.

**Edit:** Ok with multiprocessing.Queue works fine but now with similar code there is this error:

```py
$ python "Papinhio_player.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Papinhio_player.py", line 3078, in <module>
    program = PapinhioPlayerCode()
  File "Papinhio_player.py", line 250, in __init__
    self.manage_decks_instance = Manage_Decks(self)
  File "C:\python\scripts\Papinhio player\src\main\python_files/manage_decks.py"
, line 356, in __init__
    self.custom_server_child_process.start()
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, i
n start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, i
n _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 327, i
n _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_win32.py", l
ine 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60,
in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "stringsource", line 2, in av.audio.codeccontext.AudioCodecContext.__redu
ce_cython__
TypeError: self.parser,self.ptr cannot be converted to a Python object for pickl
ing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 116, in
spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 126, in
_main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: I think you need to use `multiprocessing.Queue`, to get an object that can be transferred to a different process, rather than `queue.Queue`.

Comment: Try `dill` instead of `pickle` https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Some objects cannot be serialized then unserialized.

The stack trace you posted mentions :

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

a lock, which holds a state *in memory* and gives guarantees that no other process can own the same lock *at the same moment*, is typically a very bad candidate for this operation -- what should be created when you deserialize it ?

---

To fix this : choose a way to select the relevant fields of the object you want to serialize, and pickle/unpickle that part.